# GeoServer - render ImageMosaic footprints

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, footprint

Does GeoServer have the ability to query and return footprints for an ImageMosaic? Usually the sidecar vector files defining the clipping boundary are available...so I was hoping to be able to render image footprints or an outline of some sort without creating another layer.

The purpose would be to show the presence of a raster layer without actually showing the raster data itself.

Comment: Add the index as a layer

Comment: @IanTurton This is what I was hoping to not have to do ("render image footprints or an outline of some sort without creating another layer.")

Comment: GeoServer can only display layers so if you want to see it then it has to be a layer

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a rendering transformation that will do that for you, but with a couple of limitations:

- It's going to display the rectangular footprint of your images, not the eventual clipping boundary
- Needs at least GeoServer 2.21.0 to be used.

If you are satisfied with the above, this style is an example of using the transformation, that switches from a footprint to a raster visualization as you zoom in and out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>test_layer</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Transformation>
                    <ogc:Function name="footprints"/>
                </Transformation>
                <Rule>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>100000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <PolygonSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                        <Fill>
                            <CssParameter name="fill">#AAAAAA</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                    </PolygonSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>100000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <RasterSymbolizer/>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: That's really cool, I'll test this and get back.